# how to change the selected value using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a that I want to change the selected one late using a function which is trig onClick later in the app.

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value=aa>aa</option>
<option value=bb>bb</option>
<option value=cc>cc</option>
</select>
```

then by click on a button a function will run and send a query to mysql using php. Let say that php responds me back "bb" then how can I change this select to be selected on bb??

```
document.getElementById('myselect').value="bb";
```

does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Add an identifier to your select element such as an ID, then you can just set the value with `.val()`.

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="aa">aa</option>
    <option value="bb">bb</option>
    <option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
```

In jQuery once you receive your AJAX response, set the value

```
$('#mySelect').val(phpResponseValue);
```

Where `phpResponseValue` is the value returned from the AJAX response such as `aa`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value=aa>aa</option>
<option value=bb>bb</option>
<option value=cc>cc</option>
</select>
```

jQuery :

```
$("#mySelect").val('bb');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(data){

               $('.select_class').val(data);

        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: `var value = response` is that really necessary?

Comment: That's fine now, but I suggest you be consistent with your jQuery functions for readability - `jQuery` and `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `val()` method, but you can also use the basic javascript function and properties of the select (which have a better performance)

```
select.selectedIndex
```

is the current selected index, so you can select what you want by setting this propertie

```
select.options
```

is the array of options in your select